# Merge document word in order that i want with spire.doc

Tags: c#, spire.doc

i'm trying to merge multiple word document into one document using spire.doc, but I would like the order to be my choice.

```
Document doc = new Document();

//document1
doc.LoadFromFile(sourcefile1, FileFormat.Docx);
doc.InsertTextFromFile(@"C:\document.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
doc.SaveToFile(@"C:\document.docx", FileFormat.Docx);

//document2
doc.LoadFromFile(sourcefile2, FileFormat.Docx);
doc.InsertTextFromFile(@"C:\document.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
doc.SaveToFile(@"C:\document.docx", FileFormat.Docx);

//document 3
doc.LoadFromFile(sourcefile3, FileFormat.Docx);
doc.InsertTextFromFile(@"C:\document.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
doc.SaveToFile(@"C:\document.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
```

For example I would like document1 to be on the front page but currently it is put on the last page.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve your requirement:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.LoadFromFile("file1.docx");

string[] files = new string[] {"file2.docx", "file3.docx" };

//Insert contents from multiple files into file1.docx
foreach (string file in files)
{
    doc.InsertTextFromFile(file, FileFormat.Docx);
}

//Save the result file
doc.SaveToFile("merge.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
```